# Multiple fields search with finder and results sorting

Tags: hooks, search, views

I configured a view, listing hundreds of elements, like this:
Name, Type, Result, Other

Now, I need to search it, with multiple forms, simultaneously, in this way:
Search element n.1: [INPUT]
Search element n.2: [INPUT]
Search element n.3: [INPUT]
Search element n.4: [INPUT]

I tried to implement it using "finder" module and autocomplete fields. Everything works fine, but results are sorted in the same order of the view, and there is no way to change this behavior...
I need instead to show results respecting the order of the search. So, if I search
foo, bar, foobar, I want to show first results in this order (foo, bar, foobar), not in alphabetical order like the original view.
I think I have to modify the view with a views hook, but I'm not able to fix my problem yet...
How can I sort the results of this search page?